# JSON data is not showing

Tags: javascript, json, html

I'm running two files(HTML and JSON) in my localhost and using  $.getJSON to call the JSON file.

but don't know why it is not showing the content in my table

my HTML file is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    $(function() {
   var people = [];

   $.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.feed, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
   <table id= "userdata" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>First Name</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my JSON file is :

```
{
   "feed": {
      "data": [
         {
            "name": "jack",
            "message": "hello jack",
         },
         {
            "name": "jack",
            "message": "hello jack",
         }
]
}
}
```

is the Json is not correct or the Script in html file have errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$.each(data.feed.data,` as `data` is a key from `object` which is a value of a key `feed`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not enough levels in when  you do your $.each. You still need to iterate on the items in the object "data" - so I think it'd be

```
$.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.feed.data, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

1) The JSON is not correct. Please remove the unnecessary comma after `"hello jack"`:

```
{
  "feed": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "jack",
        "message": "hello jack"
      },
      {
        "name": "jack",
        "message": "hello jack"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2) Correct the way you access data from parsed JSON (change the `$.each()` parameter to `data.feed.data`):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var people = [];

      $.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.feed.data, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "</tr>";
          $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
      }).fail(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="profile">
    <table id= "userdata" border="2">
      <thead>
      <th>First Name</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

3) Use the promise returned by request and handle the error. It will help you much easier to detect these problems in the future.